# Trying to loop through a 2D array

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through four separate time windows to utilize time as a feature for EEG data analysis but cannot figure out how to loop through the 4 time bins. I have included pictures of where the time bins are establish and the loop [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddIHA.png)&[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOWrv.png)

I have also tried reorganizing the for loop like this:
        for t in range(0,nTrainBin):
            trainData = np.full((len(chanList),nEv,config.nF,nTrainBin),np.nan)

```
        if trainBin[t][0] == trainBin[t][1]:
            trainData = zpower[:,:,:,trainBin[t][0]]
        else:
            if using_one_band == 1:
                trainData[c,:,t] = zpower[c,:,trainBin[t]], axis=2
            else:
                trainData[c,:,:,t] = zpower[c,:,:,trainBin[t]], axis=3
```

but am getting the error: "cannot unpack non-iterable int object" and am not sure why

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please take the site's [tour] and go over the [help] to get familiar with it. Especially take your time to read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]. Most importantly, if you want people to be reluctant to help you, don't post links to images. You can simply copy-paste the code as text and reformat it. Use the [formatting page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to help you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to loop through each of the lists in your trainBin list? It is a 2d array so you can access the first value [0,500] using `bin1 = trainBin[0]`. Then you can use the same logic to access the rest.

Comment: Thanks very much! I am trying to loop through the 4 bins so that I can add them as a feature to the dataframe.